# How to change order of items in SilverStripe GridField

Tags: php, content-management-system, silverstripe

I use a GridField in SilverStripe to create HTML section items that are rendered on a page. This works so far but it always displays the sections in the order that I added them to the CMS or rather by the ID it gets when it's created.

So my question is: **How can i change that order.** I don't want to manually change the IDs but would rather do a simple drag and drop.

Edit: Could the use of Elemental be a solution to this problem?

[Screenshot of the CMS view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2T9p.png)

The Page:

```php
class HomePage extends Page
{
    private static $has_many = [
        'SectionObjects' => SectionObject::class
    ];

    public function getCMSFields()
    {
        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Sections',
            $grid = GridField::create('SectionObjects', 'Sections', $this->SectionObjects(), GridFieldConfig_RecordEditor::create())
        );

        $config = $grid->getConfig();

        $dataColumns = $config->getComponentByType(GridFieldDataColumns::class);

        $dataColumns->setDisplayFields([
            'ID' => 'ID',
            'LastEdited' => 'Changed'
        ]);

        return $fields;
    }
}
```

The Section object

```php
class SectionObject extends DataObject{

    private static $db = [
        'Content' => 'Text',
        'BgColor' => Color::class
    ];

    private static $has_one = [
        'HomePage' => HomePage::class
    ];

    public function getCMSFields(){
        return new FieldList(
            TextareaField::create('Content','SectionContent'),
            ColorField::create('BgColor', 'Hintergrundfarbe')
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely using [the elemental module](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-elemental/) would allow you to have the kind of behaviour you want - but if you don't want to go to the effort of refactoring your code to comply with that module, you could use either the [gridfieldextensions](https://github.com/symbiote/silverstripe-gridfieldextensions/) or [sortablegridfield](https://github.com/UndefinedOffset/SortableGridField) module to allow you to sort the gridfield (with drag and drop) to your heart's content.